# feedparser google appengine deferred no entries?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, feedparser

I'm using feedparser in a deferred task in google app engine like this:

```
class RSSFetchHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):
      deferred.defer(parse_dk_indeed_com, feed)
```

and then in `parse_dk_indeed_com` I have the following code snippet:

```
import feedparser
    def parse_dk_indeed_com(feed):
    d = feedparser.parse(feed.url)
```

I can see that when I log asset.url it returns a valid URL and I know the feed has items in it. But when I log `len(d['entries'])` it returns 0? When I run the same snippet using nosetest the following test passes:

```
assert len(d['entries']) > 0
```

what am I missing?

Comment: What's `asset.url`? It's not anywhere in the code you're pasting. Please when you ask these questions, include the _original_ code, and as much of it as is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

it seems that I have found the error myself. It appears that Google has disabled certain libraries in app engine which is why the feedparser will not work using the snippet above. Instead I should have used urlfetch:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
import feedparser
feed = urlfetch.fetch(asset.url)

if feed.status_code == 200:
rss = feedparser.parse(feed.content)

logging.info("%d", len(rss['entries']))
```

the log now contains an entry saying 20 entries are available.

Comment: sounds odd to me, I'm using feedparser.parse(uri) and it's working good to me.

Comment: After having posted this question, I googled it and found some blog post claiming that Google had disabled certain libraries which affected feedparser. I tested downloading the content using urlfetch and it works.

Comment: What 'certain libraries'? It's true that some things such as sockets aren't available on App Engine, but nothing that should affect feedparser, much less silently.

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar problem which was related to AppEngine limits. While my original code was like this:

```
    raw_feed = urlfetch.fetch(self.rss_feed_url).content
    feed = feedparser.parse(raw_feed)
```

All the unit tests went through, but when testes when tested with dev_appserver I was getting some meaningless exceptions from feedparser that (after drilling down) appeared to be a buffer overflow (when feedparser was trying to read from the string). The feed I was trying to parse was pretty massive and I've encountered some appengine restrictions
The remedy was to substitute string with StringIO (and / or temporary files). Now my code looks like this

```
    tf = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
    tf.write(urlfetch.fetch(self.rss_feed_url).content)
    tf.seek(0)
    feed = feedparser.parse(tf)
```